# Linux make a new user and allow to access specific process and specific working directory

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, chroot

I am trying to make a web C++ compiler. Now I am stuck into a security issue of my website. I can run system("whoami"); and other malicious commands from my website to be runned on server. I am looking for a way to avoid that.

1. Website sends user written code to PHP back end server
2. PHP Server creates main.cpp file and writes code into.
3. PHP runs **shell_exec** to compile main.cpp into .exe:

`sudo g++ main.cpp -o compiled.exe`

It was achieved by modifying sudoers file by adding: `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Yeah, it works only with sudo command, because PHP-user don't have access to g++?

If I run command without sudo, I got this error:

> g++: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.

I tried to check it with `shell_exec("whoami");`, and ir returns me **www-data**. How can I allow www-data to access g++ process without a sudo?

Would be nice to solve that without using sudo command. And next problem, I can write code in C++ which prints all directories/files of my server. I think I need to make a new user and allow to access only specific home directory for that user and allow to run only g++? I readed it can be done with chroot, but I am green with servers and configurations.

I found info on the net how to allow specific user to access only X folder, but not found how to allow to use g++ also. Thanks in advance for any help and sorry for my bad English :)

Idea:

1. User registers on website
2. PHP creates **coder-1** (coder-id) user in system (linux)
3. PHP creates /var/www/site/builds/**1** directory.
4. Need to allow **coder-1** user to access only /builds/**1** directory and **g++** process to compile code which will be saved into this directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions

1.Create a new group called gcc_compile (whatever name you want)

2.Check the g++ path `which g++`

Output: `/usr/bin/g++`

3.Check permission: `ls -ld /usr/bin/g++`

Output:  `-rwxr-xr-x 4 root root 772704 Sep 30  2020 /usr/bin/g++`

4. Add permission for gcc_compile
   `chown root:gcc_compile /usr/bin/g++`
5. Add permission to path `chown php:gcc_compile /var/www/site/builds/1`
6. Add PHP users into gcc_compile group.

I Hope this works.